# What hard problems do we need to solve to break SHA, MD, DES?

Tags: algorithm, security, math, encryption, hash

I seek a STRICTLY a mathematic (and not pragmatic) answer.

We know that the hard problem behind RSA is integer factorization. If one were to solve that problem, he would easily break any RSA encryption. We already know that quantuum computers may hold the key to solving integer factorization.

My question is wether one can be formulated, and if yes, then which hard mathematical problem is behind (providing the one-wayness (is there such a word?) of) SHA, MD-x, (and although not a hash algorithm, DES, which is known to have been broken, although maybe not a mathematical way). In case of the hash functions, breaking it would mean generating (all) messages m that have the h hash value.

With that information I would like to be able to assess the long-term (let's say multi-decade long) security (ha-ha, right?) of these algorithms, in a strictly mathematical sense (sideway attacks ignored).

Comment: Sounds more like a maths question than programming...

Comment: The question is better posed to crypto.stackexchange.com.  However as a comment on it, RSA is simpler to explain mathematically than these other functions.  RSA relies on the fact e, d, and N can be found such that M^ed % N = M, but that given e, M^e%N, and N, neither d nor M can be found by any known means simpler than factoring N.  Hash and crypto functions are much more complex than this internally.  There are various breaks possible on hash functions as there are various on crypto functions.  But for more detail, you should repost the question to the crypto board.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. [crypto.se] is much better suited for this type of question.

Comment: There are no known reductions, so you can't really say: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provably_secure_cryptographic_hash_function

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a good question because for a long time, the research community could not even say itself what it means for a hash function to be secure.  I mean, if we talk in terms of Turing machines, then none of them are secure: there always exists a Turing machine that can output a collision in O(1) time for anything SHA or MD related.  It was not until our good friend Professor Phillip Rogaway came along and said the security is based upon nothing but human ignorance: https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/281.pdf .  So in other words, there is no mathematical foundation to their security.

There are actually hash functions out there that are more formally defined (such as VSH or SWIFFT), but it is not something you see in practice.

As for DES, it does have fixed size inputs and keys, so unless it is generalised to some design that scales, it also cannot be founded upon complexity theory.

One last point: yes, RSA is based upon factoring, but it is not proven that you need to factor to break it.  Much of cryptographic history involves trying to formalise the padding for RSA to make it provably secure in some sense of the definition or provable security.  To my knowledge, they never got past proving it secure in the so called random oracle model (see [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding)), which many theorists are not satisfied with.